# Error with CORS configuration on Spring Cloud Gateway

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-cloud, spring-cloud-gateway

Please Help. I am using Spring Cloud Gateway
I keep getting this Cors error:

**Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://localhost:8084/users/files' from origin 'http://localhost:4200' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.**

Here is my application.yml file

```
  cloud:
    gateway:
      globalcors:
        cors-configurations:
          '[/**]':
            allowedOrigins: "*"
            allowedMethods: "*"
```

Here is my Route Config:

```
    public RouteLocator myRoutes(RouteLocatorBuilder builder) {
        
        return builder.routes()
                .route(r -> r.path("/users/**")
                        .filters(f -> f.filter(authFilter))
                        .uri("http://localhost:8080/"))
 
                .build();
    }
```

Here is my CorsConfiguration File.

```
public class CorsConfiguration {

  private static final String ALLOWED_HEADERS = "x-requested-with, authorization, Content-Type, Content-Length, Authorization, credential, X-XSRF-TOKEN";
  private static final String ALLOWED_METHODS = "GET, PUT, POST, DELETE, OPTIONS, PATCH";
  private static final String ALLOWED_ORIGIN = "*";
  private static final String MAX_AGE = "7200"; //2 hours (2 * 60 * 60) 

  @Bean
  public WebFilter corsFilter() {
    return (ServerWebExchange ctx, WebFilterChain chain) -> {
      ServerHttpRequest request = ctx.getRequest();
      if (CorsUtils.isCorsRequest(request)) {
        ServerHttpResponse response = ctx.getResponse();
        HttpHeaders headers = response.getHeaders();
        headers.add("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", ALLOWED_ORIGIN);
        headers.add("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", ALLOWED_METHODS);
        headers.add("Access-Control-Max-Age", MAX_AGE); //OPTION how long the results of a preflight request (that is the information contained in the Access-Control-Allow-Methods and Access-Control-Allow-Headers headers) can be cached. 
        headers.add("Access-Control-Allow-Headers",ALLOWED_HEADERS);
        if (request.getMethod() == HttpMethod.OPTIONS) {
          response.setStatusCode(HttpStatus.OK);
          return Mono.empty();
        }
      }
      return chain.filter(ctx);
    };
  }

}
```

Comment: did your problem solve ?? I have same config in gateway but I'm still getting CORS error

Answer (score 0):

Can you add add-to-simple-url-handler-mapping property to your application.yml like below and try again

```
cloud:
gateway:
  globalcors:
    cors-configurations:
      '[/**]':
        allowedOrigins: "*"
        allowedMethods: "*"
    add-to-simple-url-handler-mapping: true
```

Comment: Thanks. But I already had that. no change. 
I even have this in my Gateway Security Config:
http.csrf().disable().cors().and().build();

Any other idea please ?

Answer (score 0):

In your `CorsConfiguration` you are setting the CORS headers only when it's a CORS request and don't if its a preflight request. The preflight request is the one which fails. So you need to remove the `if (CorsUtils.isCorsRequest(request))` condition.

Answer (score 0):

for the maven users, try add the following dependency:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

Fix for me

Answer (score 0):

Use option "allowed-origin-patterns: '*'". All CORS requests permitted.

```
spring:
  cloud:
    gateway:
      globalcors:
        cors-configurations:
          '[/**]' :
            allowed-origin-patterns: '*'
```